# android studio when I try add dependency into the project Gradle file I get this error

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-safe-args

```
dependencies {
   …
"android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$version_navigation"
}
```

I get this error : 
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property `version_navigation` for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Add code how you've defined `version_navigation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have missing to define version_navigation.

This can be done in your **top level** build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        version_navigation = '1.0.0'
    }
```